# SQLite - how to calculate linear regression slope?

Tags: sqlite, statistics, regression

I have a table containing data for many people over many months. To simplify it assume that preprocessing can give me a table of 
PersonID, MonthNumber, Value.

I want to calculate the linear regression for each person's values over the months available.

Essentially the question I want to answer is

> 'In general, are this persons values getting better, getting worse or staying the
>   same as time passes.'

One way to do this would be to calculate the slope of the linear regression for each person over the months I have available and determine if this slope is negative, positive or zero (or close to zero).

Does anyone have any idea how I might go about calculating the slope of the linear regression in SQLlite from a table such as I describe?

ideally the result of the query would be a table giving
PersonID, Slope, Intercept

or, better still
PersonID, MonthNumber, Slope, Intercept

so that I can see whether they are getting better, worse or the same at each month in time.

Comment: Do you know the formula in general? Do you know how to do SQL queries?

Comment: Yes to both questions but I now realise that SQLite does not have a square root function so on thinking about it I think this will do the trick to get the regression slope.

Slope = (N . Sum(XY) - (Sum(X) . (Sum(Y) ) / (N x Sum(X . X) - (Sum(X) . Sum(X))

Answer (score 1):

I think this will do it but since in SQLite you cannot use an earlier alias in a later line ie I cannot say sum(Value) as SumValue and then use SumValue like a variable I'll have to code for the summation several times.

```
SELECT   PersonID,
         ( 
         COUNT(Value) * SUM(MonthNumber * Value) 
          - ( SUM(MonthNumber) * SUM(Value) ) )
     / 
     ( 
        (COUNT(Value) * SUM(MonthNumber * MonthNumber) ) 
        - (SUM(MonthNumber) * SUM(MonthNumber) ) 
     ) AS slope
FROM     table1
GROUP BY PersonID;
```